# File upload temp location exception in servlet

Tags: java, apache, servlets, file-upload

My servlet host in free trial apache server for testing purpose. So when I tried to upload jpeg image to my image folder in that server it gives this error :

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/usr/local/shared/tomcat/dilis/temp/upload_e1bed5d1_54a9_45e0_b1ae_26732a1441fc_00000059.tmp" "write")
java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:979)
java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:203)
java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream.thresholdReached(DeferredFileOutputStream.java:178)
org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.checkThreshold(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:224)
org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.write(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:128)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:108)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
sanin.lands.web.Mobile_slt.doPost(Mobile_slt.java:137)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
```

How should I change temp directory to where I have access or any other way to do it?

Here is my servlet code :

```
if (!((FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName()) == "") ||
 (FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName()).isEmpty()))) {
    String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
    File theDir = new File(rootPath + "\\webapps\\images\\" + max_id);
      // if the directory does not exist, create it
    if (!theDir.exists()) {
        boolean result = theDir.mkdir();
        if (result) {
            System.out.println("DIR created");
        }
    }
    String fieldname = item.getFieldName(); 
    InputStream filecontent = item.getInputStream();
    File f = new File(rootPath + "\\webapps\\images\\" + max_id + "\\" + item.getName());
    try {
        //  item.write(file);
        item.write(f);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mobile_slt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Use Java NIO's `Files.createTempDirectory()`.

Comment: The exception doesn't seem to be caused by the code posted so far. It seems that the very first step of obtaining the uploaded file by the server already failed because the server itself isn't allowed to write to disk. Seeing the entire stacktrace should give clues. If that's indeed the case, contact the hosting provider support team. I also wonder if you're really allowed to write the obtained file to catalina.home afterwards this way.

Comment: posted all stacktrace

Comment: run tomcat with `root` privilege